# awk trying to print each id and associated items in a new line of an array

Tags: awk

Input

```
A1  +   1   2
A1  +   2   26
A1  +   3   7
A1  +   4   2
A1  +   5   1
A1  +   6   1
A1  +   7   0
A1  +   8   0
A1  +   9   3
A1  +   10  43
```

Expected output

```
A1,2,26,7,2,1,1,0,0,3,43
```

```
awk -v OFS="\t" '{a[$1][$3]=$NF;next} END {for (i in a) for (x=1;x<=10;x++) {printf "%s,",i,a[i][x]}; print ""}' <input> > <expected output>
```

This is just giving me one line with all values for all ids separated by a comma. I want to print each unique id (first column) independently in a new line.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See: [Changing columns to row using awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/539604/74329)

Comment: Since your real data presumably contains more than 1 ID you should have posted sample date with at least 2 IDs to demonstrate the issue and give us something we could test with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS=","
}
{
  arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] OFS:"")$NF
}
END{
  for(key in arr){
    print key,arr[key]
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                    ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  OFS=","                 ##Setting OFS as comma here.
}
{
  arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] OFS:"")$NF  ##Creating array arr with index of $1 and keep adding its value here.
}
END{                      ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(key in arr){        ##Traversing through arr here.
    print key,arr[key]    ##Printing key and value here.
  }
}
' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Please explain, this part {arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] OFS:"")$NF}. what does this do I am not familiar with it. What if I want to print A1,+,2,26,7,2,1,1,0,0,3,43? Appreciate it.

Comment: I see so {arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] OFS:"")$NF} part checks whether the id for the next line is the same as the current line and if so ? keep adding the last column $NF to this array for the same ID. Is that it? Thanks.

Comment: @Process1,sure, I had added explanation just a sec back, please do check it and let me know if any queries. For `{arr[$1]=(arr[$1]?arr[$1] OFS:"")$NF}` its like using ternary operator to keep on adding $NF(last field of current line), `?` represents to place value if condition is true, `:` represents if condition is false then place value which comes after it. Condition is `arr[$1]` to see if current index(key) item is NOT null then append  current last field to arr[$1] value.

Comment: Yes absolutely. I have been trying awk on my own. Where can I find a thorough tutorial on awk programming that covers topics like conditional append and array manipulation? Any recommendation. Thanks

Comment: @Process1, sure, personally I have learnt by `man awk` page mostly, you could also refer it, apart from that see https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-awk-programming/9781491904930/ book and https://www.math.utah.edu/docs/info/gawk_toc.html could be also helpful for learning cheers, you could try learning and wherever stuck somewhere; you could post a question on Stack overflow too :) cheers

Answer (score 2):

Here is another bit shorter `awk`:

```sh
awk -v OFS=, '{a[$1] = a[$1] OFS $4} END {for (i in a) print i a[i]}' file

A1,2,26,7,2,1,1,0,0,3,43
```

Comment: Thanks for this one line as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just rework your END block a bit

```
  END {
      for (i in a) {
          printf "%s", i
          for (x=1; x<=10; x++) printf ",%s", a[i][x]
          print ""
      }
  }
```

```
A1,2,26,7,2,1,1,0,0,3,43
```

Answer (score 0):

To retain the order of IDs from the input and not have to read all the data into memory:

```
$ awk '
    $1!=prev { if(NR>1) print prev vals; prev=$1; vals="" }
    { vals=vals "," $4 }
    END { print prev vals }
' file
A1,2,26,7,2,1,1,0,0,3,43
```

If your input isn't grouped by ID then do `sort -k1,1 -s file | awk '...'` using GNU sort for stable sort (-s)